# How to insert a row in one go with EPPlus

Tags: c#, epplus, epplus-4

I've started using EPPlus and I was wondering if there is a way to insert a row all in one go instead of having to populate cell by cell.

For example let's say my row number 6 is populated with various number, could I insert all cells in the row by separating the values with something like a comma or a tab? Something like:

```
ws.Row(6).Value = "12,45,76,12,1";
```

(I know the syntax above doesn't work, just wondering if there is a way to do something similar).
Thank you!

Comment: No, how should epplus know that this is not a single value or what happens with `1,"2,3",3`? Populate all cells, very readable and efficient.

Comment: no but im sure you could code up a method to do that for you. something like PopRow("values comma separated starting at 0 index) in could even enhance by parsing in the column index.

Comment: @TimSchmelter that wouldn't be hard to do. They could add a method called PopRow in the library as suggested by Seabizkit. Of course I can write one myself, but I wanted to make sure it doesn't exist already.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You mean like this:

```
ws.Cells[6, 1].LoadFromText("12,45,76,12,1");
```

The `Cells` object has an overload to specify `Row, Column`.  `LoadFromText` has 5 overloads so you can get very specific on how it loads the text.  The above will give this:

[image]

Comment: That's exactly it! Thank you @Ernie, I hate to reinvent the wheel even it's a  3 lines method. If you could point me to some good documentation of the EPPlus API that would be really appreciated. I could only find a couple of examples on epplus.codeplex.com

Comment: @Gep No problem.  Just be careful with the `LoadFrom*` methods when it comes to performance and very large datasets - I have actually written my own `for` loops because they can add so much overhead.  There isnt much documentation when it comes to Epplus unfortunately, other then reading the source code: http://epplus.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#EPPhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/35917601/how-to-insert-a-row-in-one-go-with-epplus/35919746?noredirect=1#lus/ExcelRangeBase.cs.  ExcelRangeBase.cs contains the `LoadFromText` overloads and tags.

Comment: Sorry, that link is bad due to the formatting:  http://epplus.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#EPPlus/ExcelRangeBase.cs